# Почему функция не принимает файл? C++

Tags: c++

Хочу организовать фукнцию, которая из открытого файла читала бы аргументы и записывала их в существующую матрицу, но почему-то функция не принимает файл. Почему, и как сделать так, чтобы принимала? [image: Код программы]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Потому что](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream) `std::fstream` нельзя копировать:

```
basic_fstream( const basic_fstream& rhs) = delete;
```

Принимайте объект по ссылке, а не по значению:

```
void readM(std::ifstream &f, //...
```